# Sources for learning iPhone Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

i am new to iPhone. i want to learn Core Data. what are the best sources to learn it. Tutorials, Books ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PragProg](http://www.pragprog.com/) have two relevant books in beta: their iPhone book includes a solid section on Core Data, and there's also their Core Data book itself.

Apple's [Core Data Tutorial for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) is actually very good indeed, and worth working through. I found it to be the resource that most helped me click into Core Data, before looking in detail at the above books. (Of course, it is also worth looking through the non-iPhone specific Core Data docs.)

Also, Jeff LaMarche (co-author of the Apress Beginning iPhone Dev) has been posting up a fair bit of Core Data content on his [blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/) lately, including paths past some basic but not always intuitive iPhone-specific gotchas. It's worth subscribing to his blog while you're getting into iPhone dev.

Comment: The Pragmatic Programmers' books on Core Data and iPhone development both have great sections on iPhone-specific Core Data and are well worth the read.  Apple's documentation on Core Data is some of their best, so I'd also suggest the Core Data Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Comment: Try this Core Data Basics Tutorial that uses Storyboards: http://timroadley.com/2012/02/09/core-data-basics-part-1-storyboards-delegation/

Answer (score 2):

I recently compiled the following resources on my blog for beginning iOS development. Here's a basic rundown, and you can hit [my blog](http://matthewcarriere.github.com) for more details. These are the resources I considered the best while I have been ramping up.

[iOS Developer Roadmap](http://matthewcarriere.github.com/blog/2011/08/10/ios-developer-roadmap/)

[Top 5 Books for Getting Started with iOS Development](http://matthewcarriere.github.com/blog/2011/08/06/top-5-books-for-getting-started-with-ios-development/)

- Beginning iPhone 4 Development
- Programming iOS 4
- Pro Objective-C Design Patterns
- iOS 4 Application Development
- Designing the iPhone User Experience

[Top 5 Video Training Resources for iOS Development](http://matthewcarriere.github.com/blog/2011/08/08/top-5-video-training-resources-for-ios-development/)

- Objective-C Essential Training
- iPhone SDK Essential Training
- Create a Compelling User Interface with Core Animation
- Developing Apps for iOS
- Apple WWDC Videos

I also just came across this great Core Data video set:

[Core Data for OS X iPhone and iPad](http://matthewcarriere.github.com/blog/2011/08/11/learning-core-data-for-iphone-and-ipad-video-tutorials/)

That should keep you busy!

Answer (score 1):

on iTunes you can get some video tutorials made by the Stanford university which aren't too bad - at least they give you a good introduction...

get it here:
https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-programming-spring-2009/id384233222

Comment: Those Stanford videos, while good, don't cover Core Data as iPhone OS 3.0 (the version at which Core Data was introduced to the iPhone) was still under NDA when they were recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Isted is writing a book, "Core Data for the iPhone," to be published by Addison-Wesley. The first four chapters of the book are in conversion and should be available on Rough Cuts in Safari (http://safari.informit.com) very soon (either later this week or sometime next week).

Email me if you'd like more info about the book.

chuck [dot] toporek [at] pearson [dot] com

Thanks,
Chuck Toporek
Senior Acquisitions Editor
Addison-Wesley Professional
Boston, MA