# Books / Videos / Ressources to dive deep into Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

My boss gave me the big mission to become an Core Data nerd. He wants me to spend at least 4 months fulltime on this topic, so that I can help with any problem that arises. Damn.

Ok... I assume you have lots of great links for me! Let me suck them into my brain like a vacuum cleaner.

Videos, Books, Ressources, etc... he gave me $500 budget for buying books and trainings! So just recommend anything you think is good, and I'll drain his pockets empty.

Comment: Seriously, that's your question? See my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sources for learning iPhone Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399322/sources-for-learning-iphone-core-data)

Comment: Things like this have to be re-asked every time. Every day new stuff comes out and won't be mentioned in old questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been there, done that...

[Sources for learning iPhone Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399322/sources-for-learning-iphone-core-data)
[Best resources for learning Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956841/best-ressources-for-learning-core-data)
[Starting point in learning Core Data on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164300/starting-point-in-learning-core-data-on-)

Amazon
[http://www.amazon.com/Core-Data-Apples-API-Persisting/dp/1934356328](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356328)